# Netlify Lambda Functions - Failing Build

Tags: node.js, lambda, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a Netlify Lambda Functions, and I'm getting this build error:

```
...
11:00:00 PM: Build script success
11:00:00 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:00:00 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Deploy directory 'build' does not exist
```

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "netlify-lambda build src/lambda"
},
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add "yarn" to the "build" script, like so:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "yarn netlify-lambda build src/lambda"
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run this command

```
npm install netlify-lambda --save
```